# How to config NGINX reverse proxy and let's encrypt certificate

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt

I have set up an Nginx server as a reverse proxy for a Python/WSGI web application. Here is the config file of the site-enabled:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        include     uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass  unix:/home/user/webapp/webapp.sock;
    }
```

I could use certbot for a setup in which Nginx was not a reverse proxy and it worked like a charm, but on the above config, when I run certbot I get the following error: `"Could not automatically find a matching server block for mydomain.com. Set the`server_name`directive to use the Nginx installer"`. According to [1](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/5817), it looks like it's a misconfiguration of Nginx. I created the certificates based on this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/768509/lets-encrypt-with-an-nginx-reverse-proxy), but I have no idea of how to config nginx to accept https using this new certificate while it is a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 1):

This config works for me:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginxSSL.log combined;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        include     uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass  unix:/home/user/webapp/webapp.sock;
    }
}
```

~